# Populate ComboBox2 depending on ComboBox1 selection

Tags: powershell, combobox

Few days of searching and trying multiple options, but nothing is working actually. With the previous code posted.

I've imported all my objects from XAML (all set in variables), I don't know if that would be a problem for that. I don't think since everything else seems to work properly.

I just want my Tab2CBB2 to show values depending on the selection of Tab1CBB1. Anyone could help ?  (I haven't paste the entire code, neither the paths but you can probably help me with that). Note that those are two of my multiple tries. Thanks

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')

[xml]$xaml = @" ...

"@

#Read XAML (Parse it)
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XAML)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

$listQA14 = Get-ChildItem $pathQA14 -name
$listQA15 = Get-ChildItem $pathQA15 -name
$listDBQA = Get-ChildItem $pathDBQA -name

$Tab1CBB1_SelectedIndexChanged= {
    $Tab1CBB2.Items.Clear() # Clear the list
    $Tab1CBB2.Text = $null  # Clear the current entry
    Switch ($Tab1CBB1.Text) {
        'QA14' {        
            $ListQA14 | ForEach { $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add($_) }
        }


        'QA15' {        
            $ListQA15 | ForEach { $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add($_) }
        }

        'ARIELDBQA' {        
            $ListDBQA | ForEach { $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add($_) }
        }
        }
        }

$Tab1CBB1.add_SelectedIndexChanged($Tab1CBB1_SelectedIndexChanged)


#Displays the Window
$Window.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Here is another option tried :

```
#ComboBox1------
$ItemsCBB1 = @('ARIELDBQA','QA14','QA15')
foreach ($Item in $ItemsCBB1) {
$Tab1CBB1.Items.Add($Item)
}


#ComboBox2-------

    if ($Tab1CBB1.SelectedItem -eq 'QA14') {
        $Tab1CBB2.Items.Clear()
        foreach ($Serie in $listQA14) {
        $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add($Serie)
        }
    }
     

    elseif ($Tab1CBB1.SelectedItem -eq 'QA15') {
        $Tab1CBB2.Items.Clear()
        foreach ($Serie in $listQA15) {
        $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add($Serie)
           }
    }

    elseif ($Tab1CBB1.SelectedItem -eq 'listDBQA') {
           $Tab1CBB2.Items.Clear()
           foreach ($Serie in $listDBQA) {
           $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add($Serie)
           }
    }
```

Tried this also : $Selection = $Tab1CBB1.SelectedItem.ToString()
Variable $selection put after 'if', but not working
Note that when I indicate what the current selection would be, it is working properly. The problem seems to come from 'recording' the selection a the time of clicking... Thnaks !

Comment: As for this  --- [Populate ComboBox2 depending on ComboBox1 selection] --- , this is a very common thing and has been a thing well before PowerShell ever existed. There are tons of examples all over the web, in many languages, as well as videos on Youtube. It's often referred to as combobox synchronization.

Comment: Thank you, but as i said, everything found was tried and nothing is working... I<m new to powershell so i<m trying to get some help ;)

Comment: Being new is fine, but then that makes it vital that you get ramped up on it first. [Youtube is your friend](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+%27combo+box%27'). WinForm/WPF is the same regardless of the code-behind language you use. So, this is really not a PowerShell specific issue, but a WinFrom/WPF design/config one. This is a common question, even here on SO, it's been asked in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420948/powershell-populate-combobox-basing-on-the-selected-item-on-another-combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, all you have to do is inside the `$Tab1CBB1_SelectedIndexChanged` scriptblock use the various lists with [script scoping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes).

Without that, the variables are unknown inside the script block.

```
$Tab1CBB1_SelectedIndexChanged = {
    $Tab1CBB2.Items.Clear() # Clear the list
    $Tab1CBB2.Text = $null  # Clear the current entry
    switch ($Tab1CBB1.Text) {
        'QA14'      { $script:ListQA14 | ForEach-Object { $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add($_) } }
        'QA15'      { $script:ListQA15 | ForEach-Object { $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add($_) } }
        'ARIELDBQA' { $script:ListDBQA | ForEach-Object { $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add($_) } }
    }
}
```

Another method could be to dynamically get the items to enter in the combobox, especially since these are file lists and can change while your form is being used:

```
$Tab1CBB1_SelectedIndexChanged = {
    $Tab1CBB2.Items.Clear() # Clear the list
    $Tab1CBB2.Text = $null  # Clear the current entry
    switch ($Tab1CBB1.Text) {
        'QA14'      { $path = $script:pathQA14 ; break }
        'QA15'      { $path = $script:pathQA15 ; break }
        'ARIELDBQA' { $path = $script:pathDBQA }
    }
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Name | ForEach-Object { $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add($_) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of what you seem to be after is something like this.

```
### Powershell populate ComboBox 2 based on ComboBox 1 Selection
Add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'

$labelDoubleClickOnAnyItem = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'

$listbox2 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox'
$listbox1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox'

$buttonOK = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'

$form1_Load={
    $items=1..9 | 
    ForEach-Object {"List item $_"}
    
    $listbox1.Items.AddRange($items)
}

$listbox1_MouseDoubleClick=[System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler]{
    $listbox2.Items.Add($listbox1.SelectedItem)
    $listbox1.Items.Remove($listbox1.SelectedItem)
}

$listbox2_MouseDoubleClick=[System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler]{
    $listbox1.Items.Add($listbox2.SelectedItem)
    $listbox2.Items.Remove($listbox2.SelectedItem)
}

$form1.Controls.Add($labelDoubleClickOnAnyItem)
$form1.Controls.Add($listbox2)
$form1.Controls.Add($listbox1)
$form1.Controls.Add($buttonOK)
$form1.AcceptButton = $buttonOK
$form1.ClientSize = '378, 388'
$form1.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
$form1.MaximizeBox = $False
$form1.MinimizeBox = $False
$form1.Name = 'form1'
$form1.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form1.Text = 'Form'
$form1.add_Load($form1_Load)

$labelDoubleClickOnAnyItem.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif, 9.75pt, style=Bold, Italic'
$labelDoubleClickOnAnyItem.Location = '13, 13'
$labelDoubleClickOnAnyItem.Name = 'labelDoubleClickOnAnyItem'
$labelDoubleClickOnAnyItem.Size = '353, 41'
$labelDoubleClickOnAnyItem.TabIndex = 3
$labelDoubleClickOnAnyItem.Text = 'Double click on any item to move it from one box to the other.'

$listbox2.FormattingEnabled = $True
$listbox2.Location = '200, 67'
$listbox2.Name = 'listbox2'
$listbox2.Size = '166, 277'
$listbox2.Sorted = $True
$listbox2.TabIndex = 2
$listbox2.add_MouseDoubleClick($listbox2_MouseDoubleClick)

$listbox1.FormattingEnabled = $True
$listbox1.Location = '12, 67'
$listbox1.Name = 'listbox1'
$listbox1.Size = '167, 277'
$listbox1.Sorted = $True
$listbox1.TabIndex = 1
$listbox1.add_MouseDoubleClick($listbox1_MouseDoubleClick)

$buttonOK.Anchor = 'Bottom, Right'
$buttonOK.DialogResult = 'OK'
$buttonOK.Location = '291, 353'
$buttonOK.Name = 'buttonOK'
$buttonOK.Size = '75, 23'
$buttonOK.TabIndex = 0
$buttonOK.Text = '&OK'

$form1.ShowDialog()
```

Or even this using just the ComboBox elements

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(498,459)
$Form.text                       = 'Form'
$Form.TopMost                    = $false
$Form.StartPosition              = 'CenterScreen'

$ComboBox1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$ComboBox1.text                  = ''
$ComboBox1.width                 = 216
$ComboBox1.height                = 75
@('ComboxItem1','ComboxItem2','ComboxItem3') | 
ForEach-Object {[void] $ComboBox1.Items.Add($_)}
$ComboBox1.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(31,41)
$ComboBox1.Font                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$ComboBox2                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$ComboBox2.text                  = ''
$ComboBox2.width                 = 213
$ComboBox2.height                = 38
$ComboBox2.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(32,73)
$ComboBox2.Font                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

Function Add-ItemToComboBox2
{
    $ComboBox2.Items.Add($ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    $ComboBox2.Refresh()
}

$Form.controls.AddRange(
    @(
        $ComboBox1,
        $ComboBox2
    )
)

$ComboBox1.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({ Add-ItemToComboBox2 })

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

You have not stated what UX/UI tool you are using to design and implement your
GUI. Yet, hard coding is also just a challenge. So consider using one of these for your UX/UI effort. Your UX/UI should just work, whether you have PowerShell code behind it (or any other language). Your PowerShell code should just work, regardless of the UX/UI that may be implemented. Your UX/UI code should be separate from your ops code. You call your ops code from the UX/UI.

***Free:***

> https://poshgui.com
>
> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=poshgui
>
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community
>
> Be sure to thoroughly read the licensing agreement for VS.
>
> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=vs+2019+community+winforms

***Purchase***

> https://ironmansoftware.com/psscriptpad
>
> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=psscriptpad
>
> https://ironmansoftware.com/powershell-pro-tools
>
> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell-pro-tools
>
> https://www.sapien.com/software/powershell_studio
>
> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Sapien%27s+powershell+studio++winforms
>
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs
>
> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=vs+2019+community+winforms

Comment: Thank you very much. The only line i needed was : $ComboBox1.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({ Add-ItemToComboBox2 })  and put all my stuff in it. I've already tried it but the ({}) wasnt at the proper place !