# Check item into List box by Radio Button

Tags: powershell, active-directory, listbox, radio-button, checkedlistbox

I'm trying to check an item into a ListBox after clicking a Radio Button, but no success.
Specifically, I'm trying to check a Active Directory Group already listed.

I made this piece of script:

```
$Action = foreach ($SecurityGroup in $ADSecurityGroup)
                      {
                        $SecurityGroup.Name -eq "AD Example"
                        {
                           [void] $ADGroups.Items.Add($SecurityGroup.Name, $True)
                        }
                      }
```

And after added to Add_Click of Raddio Button:

```
$RadioButton.Add_Click($Action)
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: This is really not a PowerShell issue. It's a UX/UI design implementation via form events. There are many examples all over the web and on Youtube showing and providing examples for how to do this. Also, user real UX/UI design tools will make this far easier for you. There are a few, that are free, like https:poshgui.com and MS Visual Studio Community Edition (be sure to fully read the EULA on VS  as it has use case licensing limits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved what I was looking for with this:

```
$RadioButton.Add_Click({
                            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $ADGroups.Items.Count; $i++)
                                {
                                    If ($ADGroups.Items[$i] -match 'AD Group that I wanted to change status')
                                        {
                                           $ADGroups.SetItemChecked($i, $true)
                                        }
                                 }
                          })
```

I publish it in case it is useful to someone.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I provide to another OP, though it's using a list box, and a comboxbox, the premise for doing this via a button in the same.

[Populate ComboBox2 depending on ComboBox1 selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849654/populate-combobox2-depending-on-combobox1-selection)

Another example of Comboxbox to a list
(You could just change the combobox to whatever form element you choose) :

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$ComboBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$ComboBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$ComboBox.Items.AddRange(@("One","Two"))


$RichTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$RichTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$Form.Controls.Add($ComboBox)
$Form.Controls.Add($RichTextBox)


$ComboBox.Add_TextChanged({


    # Code here
    switch($ComboBox.Text){
    "One" {$RichTextBox.Text = "This is one"}
    "Two" {$RichTextBox.Text = "This is two"}

    }

})

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

As for this...

> Specifically, I'm trying to check an Active Directory Group already
> listed.

... you just do validation before your add another item.